# Unable to send Flux messages to the mock ReactorNettyWebSocketClient

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactor-netty

In my Java Spring boot application, I am using reactive libraries to connect and stream from a websocket. I have the following dependencies in my `pom.xml` file

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.8</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

My production code to open a websocket connection looks like

```
@Autowired private ReactorNettyWebSocketClient client;

 public <T> Flux<T> connectToWebSocketAndParseMessages(
      String websocketUrl, Function<String, T> deserializer) {
    return Flux.create(
        sink -> {
          try {
            client
                .execute(new URI(websocketUrl), getWebSocketHandler(deserializer, sink))
                .retryWhen(getRetrySpec())
                .subscribe(); // Subscribe to start the WebSocket connection
          } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            sink.error(e);
          }
        });
  }

  @NotNull
  private <T> WebSocketHandler getWebSocketHandler(
      Function<String, T> deserializer, FluxSink<T> sink) {
    return session -> {
      Flux<WebSocketMessage> messageFlux = session.receive();
      return messageFlux
          .map(
              message -> {
                String messagePayload = message.getPayloadAsText();
                try {
                  T model = deserializer.apply(messagePayload);
                  sink.next(model); // Emit the parsed model
                } catch (Exception e) {
                  sink.error(e); // Handle parsing errors by signaling an error
                }
                return messagePayload;
              })
          .then();
    };
  }
```

Now, I am trying to unit test the method `connectToWebSocketAndParseMessages` and for this, I mock the `ReactorNettyWebSocketClient` and the session created by the client. My test case looks like

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:test.properties")
class WebSocketGatewayTest {

  @Autowired private WebSocketGateway webSocketGateway;

  @MockBean private ReactorNettyWebSocketClient mockClient;

  @Test
  public void testConnectToWebSocketAndParseMessages1() {
    // Given
    Function<String, Integer> deserializer = Integer::parseInt;
    String websocketUrl = "ws://example.com";
    WebSocketSession session = mock(WebSocketSession.class);
    WebSocketMessage message1 = mock(WebSocketMessage.class);
    WebSocketMessage message2 = mock(WebSocketMessage.class);

    when(mockClient.execute(any(URI.class), any()))
        .thenReturn(Flux.just(session).then())
        .thenAnswer(
            invocation -> {
              WebSocketHandler handler = invocation.getArgument(1);
              handler.handle(session); // Simulate WebSocket session handling
              return Mono.empty();
            });

    when(session.receive()).thenReturn(Flux.just(message1, message2));
    when(message1.getPayloadAsText()).thenReturn("42");
    when(message2.getPayloadAsText()).thenReturn("100");

    // When
    Flux<Integer> result =
        webSocketGateway.connectToWebSocketAndParseMessages(websocketUrl, deserializer);

    // Then
    StepVerifier.create(result).expectNext(42).expectNext(100).expectComplete().verify();
  }
// remaining tests
```

Now, once the test runs, it does not complete and keeps on waiting for the message to be received from the websocket. The mock `when(mockClient.execute(any(URI.class), any()))` somehow does not send any message to the websocket and this causes the test to not complete.

Any ideas here as to how this test can be modified to test the behaviour of reactive websocket connection. Thanks

Comment: Why do you use a sink to process the data? I'm not sure it's the cause of the unit test problem, but it's definitely a wrong way to use Reactor

Comment: I have this `connectToWebSocketAndParseMessages ` called from multiple places and I tried to extract it to a class from where I could use this. Hence in an effort to make it generic, I introduced a `sink`. Could you please point out to me the correct way to read from a websocket ? Thanks

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that. Now I see what you're trying to do.